# How to get information from the nested tags when with a python bs4?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the GitHub trending page and here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_github = "https://github.com/trending"


def request_github_trending(url):
    request = requests.get(url)
    return request


def extract(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find_all('article', class_="Box-row")


def transform(html_repos):
    for repo in html_repos:
        stars = repo.find('a', class_="Link--muted d-inline-block mr-3")
        print(stars)
        break


print(transform(extract(request_github_trending(url_github))))
```

I want to parse number of stars then I got this result:

```
<a class="Link--muted d-inline-block mr-3" data-view-component="true" href="/rocketseat-education/nlw6-discover/stargazers">
<svg aria-label="star" class="octicon octicon-star" data-view-component="true" height="16" role="img" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 16 16" width="16">
<path d="M8 .25a.75.75 0 01.673.418l1.882 3.815 4.21.612a.75.75 0 01.416 1.279l-3.046 2.97.719 4.192a.75.75 0 01-1.088.791L8 12.347l-3.766 1.98a.75.75 0 01-1.088-.79l.72-4.194L.818 6.374a.75.75 0 01.416-1.28l4.21-.611L7.327.668A.75.75 0 018 .25zm0 2.445L6.615 5.5a.75.75 0 01-.564.41l-3.097.45 2.24 2.184a.75.75 0 01.216.664l-.528 3.084 2.769-1.456a.75.75 0 01.698 0l2.77 1.456-.53-3.084a.75.75 0 01.216-.664l2.24-2.183-3.096-.45a.75.75 0 01-.564-.41L8 2.694v.001z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>
        128
</a>
None
```

How I can get only the numbers? And also, I have tried to parse repository name and developers name. But messed up with this. Could not get the developer's name, the situation with repository name can get only part before the slash. I will appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the "stars", you can use the [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method.
To get the "repository", you can use the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) method

With this example, I have included how to get *all* information, including the "repository", "stars", and the developers name ("built buy").

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_github = "https://github.com/trending"


def request_github_trending(url):
    request = requests.get(url)
    return request


def extract(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    return soup.find_all("article", class_="Box-row")


def print_info(html):
    fmt_string = "{:<60} {:<30} {}"
    print(fmt_string.format("Repo", "Stars", "Built by"))
    print("-" * 150)
    for tag in html:
        repository_info = tag.find(class_="text-normal")
        repository = repository_info.text.strip() + repository_info.next_sibling.strip()

        stars = tag.find(class_="Link--muted d-inline-block mr-3").get_text(strip=True)

        usernames = [user["alt"] for user in tag.find_all("img")]
        print(fmt_string.format(repository, stars, usernames))


print_info(extract(request_github_trending(url_github)))
```

Output:

```
Repo                                                         Stars                          Built by
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rocketseat-education /nlw6-discover                          129                            ['@jakeliny']
six-ddc /plow                                                1,531                          ['@six-ddc', '@chenrui333', '@dependabot', '@musinit']
flutter /flutter                                             123,023                        ['@engine-flutter-autoroll', '@abarth', '@Hixie', '@jonahwilliams', '@HansMuller']
n8n-io /n8n                                                  15,781                         ['@janober', '@RicardoE105', '@ivov', '@Rupenieks', '@krynble']
PaddlePaddle /PaddleClas                                     1,521                          ['@littletomatodonkey', '@weisy11', '@dyning', '@Intsigstephon', '@cuicheng01']
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Let's say..

```
output = <a class="Link--muted d-inline-block mr-3" data-view-component="true" href="/rocketseat-education/nlw6-discover/stargazers">
<svg aria-label="star" class="octicon octicon-star" data-view-component="true" height="16" role="img" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 16 16" width="16">
<path d="M8 .25a.75.75 0 01.673.418l1.882 3.815 4.21.612a.75.75 0 01.416 1.279l-3.046 2.97.719 4.192a.75.75 0 01-1.088.791L8 12.347l-3.766 1.98a.75.75 0 01-1.088-.79l.72-4.194L.818 6.374a.75.75 0 01.416-1.28l4.21-.611L7.327.668A.75.75 0 018 .25zm0 2.445L6.615 5.5a.75.75 0 01-.564.41l-3.097.45 2.24 2.184a.75.75 0 01.216.664l-.528 3.084 2.769-1.456a.75.75 0 01.698 0l2.77 1.456-.53-3.084a.75.75 0 01.216-.664l2.24-2.183-3.096-.45a.75.75 0 01-.564-.41L8 2.694v.001z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>
        128
</a>
```

Just do: `output.text.strip()`. You will get `128`

*Avoid these kind of function calling - `transform(extract(request_github_trending(url_github)))`.*